# I can't access Laravel through http://(name)

Tags: php, laravel, localhost

I have recently purchased a new computer and I am trying to get my website to find laravel.  I have installed both wamp and composer.  I am able to create a new laravel project using composer create-project... I have made a VirtualHost and a hostname as such..

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /wamp/www/jaycousins/public
ServerName jaycousins
<Directory "/wamp/www/jaycousins/public">
Options +Indexes
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>


# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       jaycousins
```

But I cant find laravel simply by searching http://jaycousins/

I find it by http://localhost/jaycousins/public... How do i fix this?

Comment: move the _index.php_ to the outer folder and change the paths inside.

Comment: My other computer didn't  need to do that, so that doesn't seem like thats the problem.

Comment: Try setting the `<Directory` to `"/wamp/www/jaycousins/"`

Comment: Turns out I didn't uncomment Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf in my httpd.conf...and then i also didn't add </Directory> at the end of the Virtual Host.  It works now

Answer (score 0):

You give full path of directory

```
<Directory "<< Directory Full path >>">
```

**E.g.**

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/jaycousins/public">
```

Wamp config Reference 
https://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp